# Is there a Python built-in method that checks if an integer is in binary format or not?

Tags: python, binary, binary-data, built-in

I know the logic behind implementing my own but there a **built-in** Python function that takes an integer and returns True if it is written in binary form?

For example, `is_binary(0b1010)` would return `True` but `is_binary(12)` would return `False`.

Comment: No, it's impossible. The function only sees the value of the int, not how you represented it in your code. The values `0b1010` and `10` are indistinguishable.

Comment: At the point when the function is called there is no difference between `0b1010` and `10` anymore.

Comment: No. `0b1010` becomes `10` long before it even passed to the so-called `is_binary` function

Comment: You cannot "roll your own" for your example either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, since `0b1010` is converted to the same representation as `10` by the 'compiler', which of course happens long before it is being passed to the function.

We can confirm this by investigating the produced code.

```
import dis

def binary():
    a = 0b1010

def base_10():
    a = 10

dis.dis(binary)
print()
dis.dis(base_10)
```

Outputs

```
 17           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (10)   # <-- Same represntation here
              2 STORE_FAST               0 (a)
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              6 RETURN_VALUE

 20           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (10)   # <-- as here
              2 STORE_FAST               0 (a)
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

If it is that important for you, you will have to implement some sort of [AST parser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) which I *assume* will be able to grab the binary literal before it is converted.

Comment: This answer gives the misleading impression that `10` is "normal" somehow and `0b1010` isn't. Both `10` and `0b1010` express the exact same value, which is just an integer and doesn't have any inherent base. The default `repr` gives decimal, but the int isn't inherently decimal. (The CPython implementation happens to represent integers in either base 2^15 or base 2^30, but this is an implementation detail with no impact on int semantics.)

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica of course `0b1010` is as normal as `10` is :) I'll try to express that better than just using quotes.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I gave it another shot, please feel free to rephrase as you see fit

Answer (score 0):

If you really need such functionality and don't care for performance, you could tokenize the source:

```
scenox@Mac ~ % echo 'print(0b1010)' | python3 -m tokenize
1,0-1,5:            NAME           'print'        
1,5-1,6:            OP             '('            
1,6-1,12:           NUMBER         '0b1010'       
1,12-1,13:          OP             ')'            
1,13-1,14:          NEWLINE        '\n'           
2,0-2,0:            ENDMARKER      ''
```

So you can do something like that:

```
g = tokenize(BytesIO(somestring.encode('utf-8')).readline)  # tokenize the string
for toknum, tokval, _, _, _ in g:
    if toknum == NUMBER and tokval.startswith('0b'):
    ...
```